# Add dynamic row rank to shiny DT

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, dt

I am trying to add a row rank from smallest value to largest value in my shiny Data Table based on the order of the rows. I want the row rank to update based on the column that is ordered. My best ideas would either be to use `rownames` but those change with the rows or to use `input$table_state$order` and `saveState` to figure out what column is being ordered and then recalculate a `rank` column. I've included an example using the `iris` dataset.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

data = iris %>% distinct(Species, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
    arrange(Sepal.Length) %>%
    mutate(rank = 1:3) %>%
    select(rank, Species, everything())


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
 DT::dataTableOutput("table")
)


# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

output$table = DT::renderDataTable({
DT::datatable(data,
              rownames = FALSE,
              options = list(
                columnDefs = list(list(orderable = FALSE, targets = 0:1)),
                order = list(list(2, "asc")),
                ordering = TRUE
              ))
})

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I don't understand what is the expectation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shiny DT: Freeze rownames while sorting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57060061/shiny-dt-freeze-rownames-while-sorting)